# Extracting elements of a graph in Haskell

Tags: haskell, graph, functional-programming, custom-data-type

I have a little question concerning Haskell.
If I have data type representing a graph like this one :

```
import Data.Map (Map,empty,member,insert)

import Graphviz

-- | A directed graph
    data Graph v = Graph
    { arcsMap :: Map v [v]     -- A map associating a vertex with its 
                                  successors
    , labelMap :: Map v String -- The Graphviz label of each node
    , styleMap :: Map v String -- The Graphviz style of each node
    }
```

And i want to create a list by accessing every vertices of a given graph.

Like this:

```
-- | Returns the list of vertices of a graph in ascending order
--
-- >>> vertices emptyGraph
-- []
-- >>> vertices $ addVertices emptyGraph [1,4,5,2,1]
-- [1,2,4,5]
vertices :: Graph v -> [v]
```

My question is how can I tell Haskell to look into every vertices in arcsMap and create a list with it ?
Thankyou !!!

Comment: Are all the vertices keys? You could try `vertices = keys . arcsMap` (You got to import keys from Data.Map)

Comment: @Garrison OHHHH it worked, I never would have figured it out. How should I think to come up with some reasoning like this? I didn't know the existence of keys in Data.Map and I never found it in the documentation of Data.Map. Thank you.

Comment: Nice :) I'm not sure, I knew about keys. I usually just think about what type I am looking for and search for it on hoogle https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Map%20k%20a%20-%3E%20%5Bk%5D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function [`keys`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html#v:keys) returns all keys of the map. So you could implement `vertices` like this:

```
vertices :: Graph v -> [v]
vertices = keys . arcsMap
```